# updating Hbase table using pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, hbasestorage

I am aware that different columns of a row in HBase can be updated using Put. I am using Pig + HBase with HBaseStorage. I'm able to store and load in HBase without any issues with Pig expression where keys don't exist in the table. But, the job is failing when I've started trying to update a table with HBaseStorage() where the keys exist.

Could someone please clarify if HBaseStorage can only be used to store new records or update columns in existing records as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the HBaseStorage code there doesn't seem to be any limiting factor for that. Can you please supply the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use HBaseStorage to update columns in existing records.
If you provide us with your error message for more details.